# Piecewise linear integer curve interpolation in C#/Unity3D

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine, interpolation, linear-interpolation

Is there a simple, efficient way to implement a piecewise linear integer-to-integer curve interpolation in C# (for Unity3D, if it matters) ?
Details are as follows:

- The piecewise linear curve representation has to be built over time. The first interpolation request comes before we have all data points
- The curve is strictly monotonous
- The first point is always (0, 0)
- The data points' first coordinates are also strictly monotonous w.r.t arrival time, i.e. the points are naturally ordered by their first coordinate.
- The data points are not in ranges that would cause cause overflow problems for 4-byte integers
- The output does not have to be 100% accurate, so rounding errors are not an issue.

In C++, I would do something like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

typedef pair<int, int> tDataPoint;
typedef vector<tDataPoint> tPLC;

void appendData(tPLC& curve, const tDataPoint& point) {
  assert(curve.empty() || curve.back().first < point.first);
  curve.push_back(point);
}

int interpolate(const tPLC& curve, int cursor) {
  assert(!curve.empty());
  int result = 0;  
  // below zero, the value is a constant 0
  if (cursor > 0) {
    // find the first data point above the cursor
    const auto upper = upper_bound(begin(curve), end(curve), cursor);
    // above the last data point, the value is a constant 0
    if (upper == end(curve)) {
      result = curve.back().second;
    } else {
      // get the point below or equal to the cursor
      const auto lower = upper - 1;
      // lerp between
      float linear = float((cursor - lower.first) * (upper.second - lower.second)) / (upper.first - lower.first);
      result = lower.second + int(linear);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

I can see how I could do something that work sort of like this in C#, but nothing as concise or efficient. Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT:
I do not need to be more accurate, and am perfectly happy with piecewise linear interpolation, so better interpolation quality is not my problem here.
What I am looking for is an efficient, concise way of doing this. By efficient, I mean things like: relying on the fact that the data points are naturally ordered to be able to use binary search to find the proper segment

Answer (score 2):

I would use this interpolation cubic:

```
x=a0+a1*t+a2*t*t+a3*t*t*t
y=b0+b1*t+b2*t*t+b3*t*t*t
```

where `a0..a3` are computed like this:

```
d1=0.5*(p2.x-p0.x);
d2=0.5*(p3.x-p1.x);
a0=p1.x;
a1=d1;
a2=(3.0*(p2.x-p1.x))-(2.0*d1)-d2;
a3=d1+d2+(2.0*(-p2.x+p1.x));
```

`b0 .. b3` are computed in same way but use `y` coordinates of course

 `p0..p3` are control points for cubic interpolation curve

 `t = < 0.0 , 1.0 >` is curve parameter from `p1` to `p2`

This ensures that position and first derivation is continuous (c1). **If you want to do this on integer math then just scale `ai,bi` ant `t` accordingly.** You can also add as many dimensions as you need in the same manner

Now you need some parameter to go through your interpolation points for example `u = <0 , N-1>`

`p(0..N-1)` are your control points list

 `u = 0` means start point `p(0)`

 `u = N-1` means end point `p(N-1)`

 `P0..P3` are control points used for interpolation

So you need to compute `t` and select which points to use for interpolation

```
    double t=u-floor(u); // fractional part between control points
    int i=floor(u);       // integer part points to starting control point used
         if (i<1)     { P0=p(  0),P1=p(  0),P2=p(  1),P3=p(  2); }               // handle start edge case
    else if (i==N-1) { P0=p(N-2),P1=p(N-1),P2=p(N-1),P3=p(N-1); }  // handle end edge case
    else if (i>=N-2) { P0=p(N-3),P1=p(N-2),P2=p(N-1),P3=p(N-1); }  // handle end edge case
    else              { P0=p(i-1),P1=p(i  ),P2=p(i+1),P3=p(i+2); }

    (x,y) = interpolation (P0,P1,P2,P3,t);
```

**If you want to do this on integer math then just scale `u,t` accordingly.** If `N<3` then use linear interpolation ... or duplicate end points until `N>=3`

**[edit1] linear interpolation approach**

```
struct pnt { int x,y; };

pnt interpolate (pnt *p,int N,int x)
    {
    int i,j;
    pnt p;
    for (j=1,i=N-1;j<i;j<<=1); j>>=1; if (!j) j=1; // this just determine max mask for binary search ... can do it on p[] size change
    for (i=0;j;j>>=1) // binary search by x coordinate output is i as point index with  p[i].x<=x
        {
        i|=j;
        if (i>=N) { i-=j; continue; }
        if (p[i].x==x) break;
        if (p[i].x> x) i-=j;
        }
    p.x=x;
    p.y=p[i].y+((p[i+1].y-p[i].y)*(x-p[i].x)/(p[i+1].x-p[i].x))
    return p;
    }
```

add edge cases handling like `x` is out of points bound or point list is too small

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't think it addresses my problem, which is about performing piecewise linear interpolation efficiently, not about improving the quality of my interpolatio strategy. Concretely, one of the problems I am looking a solution for here, in your notation, is finding `u` efficiently, which is done using `upper_bound` in my C++ code. I edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: I get it now ... the curve had me confused I assume your cursor is mine u and it is bound to one of the coordinates (like x) , then simple binary search inside you point list will get you your point indexes

Comment: @Martin J. added edit1 with first point binary search ... hope did not make some typo ...

Comment: Thanks for the effort, and +1 for that. Now, I know how to implement a binary search, but if you look at the C++ code, one of the nice parts is that all this stuff is hidden in a relatively generic upper_bound algorithm. What I am looking for is the C# equivalent of that, or anything like it that would solve my problem. For instance, C# generic `List<T>` has `BinarySearch`, but apparently no equivalent that allows you get the closest match...