# Algorithm for connecting points in a graph with curved lines

Tags: algorithm, math, graph

I need to develop an algorithm that connects points in a **non-linear** way, that is, with ***smooth curves***, as in the image below:

[image: insert description of image here]

The problem is that I can not find the best solution, either using [Bezier Curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve), [Polimonial Interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation), [Curve Adjustment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting), among others.

In short, I need a formula that interpolates the points according to the figure above, generating N intermediate points between one coordinate and another.

In the image above, the first coordinate (c1) is (x = 1, y = 220) and the second (c2) is (x = 2, y = 40).

So if I want to create for example 4 intermediate coordinates between c1 and c2 I will have to get an array (x, y) of 4 elements something like this:

```
[1.2, 180], [1.4, 140], [1.6, 120], [1.8, 80]
```

Would anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You didn't say what was wrong with the other attempts, but this looks like a cubic spline in one variable to me.  See:  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicSpline.html ... except that the inflection between 6 and 7 seems unnatural

Comment: @MattTimmermans that is most likely because the starting and ending control points are not visible ...

Comment: any cubic interpolation should fit the bill for example like this: [Piecewise curve interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22806242/2521214)

Comment: @Matt Timmermans and @Spektre, thanks, but I think I'm a few steps behind your knowledge. I am not a mathematician and I do not have much intimacy with advanced formulas. It is easier for my understanding to see a code from any working language to understand the "step by step". Could you help me with that? For example, as in the example I put above, between the first two known points (x = 1 and x = 2), how would I compute `y` when x is = 1.2, 1.4, and so on?

Comment: If the points you have are evenly spaced like the picture you posted, then I show an easy way in python here: http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/mtimmerm/IPythonNotebooks/blob/master/NaturalCubicSplines.ipynb

Comment: @Matt Timmermans, Thanks, this helps, although it looks like your code uses an external library with the `hermite_interp` function that contains additional algorithms, right? Also, what if there were no uniform spacing between the points?

Comment: that's in plothelp.py over here: https://github.com/mtimmerm/IPythonNotebooks  If you don't have evenly spaced points then the math is a lot more difficult.  That's the link I gave you first

Comment: @RogérioDec all the parametric curves like BEZIER,SPLINE, ... take as input your known points  (called control points) , compute polynomial coefficients (`a0,a1,a2,a3` for cubics) (separately per each dimension and then you can compute any point on the patch using parameter `t=<0,1>`. You are not specifying the x coordinate you simply loop through `t` with small enough step and compute `x,y,z,...` points. If you need to have specific `x` then you need to compute/guess/search `t` which would lead to your `x` and then compute `y,z,...` for it....

Comment: @RogérioDec the math behind cubics is not complicated and the code in the link I shared is already computing all you need no need to derive anything ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think any [Piecewise curve interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22806242/2521214) should do it. Here small **C++** example:

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
const int n=7;      // points
const int n2=n+n;
float pnt[n2]=      // points x,y ...
    {
    1.0, 220.0,
    2.0,  40.0,
    3.0,-130.0,
    4.0,-170.0,
    5.0,- 40.0,
    6.0,  90.0,
    7.0, 110.0,
    };
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void getpnt(float *p,float t)   // t = <0,n-1>
    {
    int i,ii;
    float *p0,*p1,*p2,*p3,a0,a1,a2,a3,d1,d2,tt,ttt;
    // handle t out of range
    if (t<=      0.0f){ p[0]=pnt[0]; p[1]=pnt[1]; return; }
    if (t>=float(n-1)){ p[0]=pnt[n2-2]; p[1]=pnt[n2-1]; return; }
    // select patch
    i=floor(t);             // start point of patch
    t-=i;                   // parameter <0,1>
    i<<=1; tt=t*t; ttt=tt*t;
    // control points
    ii=i-2; if (ii<0) ii=0; if (ii>=n2) ii=n2-2; p0=pnt+ii;
    ii=i  ; if (ii<0) ii=0; if (ii>=n2) ii=n2-2; p1=pnt+ii;
    ii=i+2; if (ii<0) ii=0; if (ii>=n2) ii=n2-2; p2=pnt+ii;
    ii=i+4; if (ii<0) ii=0; if (ii>=n2) ii=n2-2; p3=pnt+ii;
    // loop all dimensions
    for (i=0;i<2;i++)
        {
        // compute polynomial coeficients
        d1=0.5*(p2[i]-p0[i]);
        d2=0.5*(p3[i]-p1[i]);
        a0=p1[i];
        a1=d1;
        a2=(3.0*(p2[i]-p1[i]))-(2.0*d1)-d2;
        a3=d1+d2+(2.0*(-p2[i]+p1[i]));
        // compute point coordinate
        p[i]=a0+(a1*t)+(a2*tt)+(a3*ttt);
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void gl_draw()
    {
    glClearColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    // set 2D view 
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glScalef(1.0/5.0,1.0/500.0,1.0);
    glTranslatef(-4.0,0.0,0.0);

    // render lines
    glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);
    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
    float p[2],t;
    for (t=0.0;t<=float(n-1);t+=0.1f)
        {
        getpnt(p,t);
        glVertex2fv(p);
        }
    glEnd();

    // render points
    glPointSize(4.0);
    glColor3f(0.0,0.0,1.0);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    for (int i=0;i<n2;i+=2) glVertex2fv(pnt+i);
    glEnd();
    glPointSize(1.0);

    glFinish();
    SwapBuffers(hdc);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here preview:

[image: preview]

As you can see it is simple you just need `n` control points `pnt` (I extracted from your graph) and just interpolate ... The `getpnt` functions will compute any point on the curve addressed by parameter `t=<0,n-1>`. Internally it just select which cubic patch to use and compute as single cubic curve. In `gl_draw` you can see how to use it to obtain the points in between.

As your control points are uniformly distributed on the `x` axis:

```
x = <1,7>
t = <0,6>
```

I can write:

```
x = t+1
t = x-1
```

so you can compute any point for any `x` too...

The shape does not match your graph perfectly because the selected control points are not the correct ones. Any local minimum/maximum should be a control point and sometimes is safer to use also inflex points too. The starting and ending shape of the curve suggest hidden starting and ending control point which is not showed on the graph. You can use any number of points you need but beware if you break the x uniform distribution then you lose the ability to compute `t` from `x` directly!

As we do not know how the graph was created we can only guess ...

Comment: Sorry by my delay. That is perfect! Thank you very much for your work and for your support!