# 3D interpolation between curves

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, math, interpolation

I have a set of curves that are temperature dependent.
I.e curve Mat1 is for temperature 310C and Mat2 is for temp 420C.

[image]

As you can see, the data looks better when put in a logarithmic scale;

[image]

Now I need to get Mat3 curve for temperature 370C by interpolating Mat1 and Mat2 curves. What is the best way to get around doing this? I'm guessing that I might need to do some sort of 3D interpolation. The nature of the data (logarithmic behavior) also needs to be considered.

Here's the data for Mat1

```
9.43E+06    6.00E+04
3.96E+06    6.20E+04
1.78E+06    6.40E+04
8.52E+05    6.60E+04
4.28E+05    6.80E+04
2.25E+05    7.00E+04
1.23E+05    7.20E+04
6.95E+04    7.40E+04
4.05E+04    7.60E+04
2.43E+04    7.80E+04
1.49E+04    8.00E+04
9.39E+03    8.20E+04
```

Here's the data for Mat2

```
5.14E+08    4.80E+04
1.35E+08    5.00E+04
4.36E+07    5.20E+04
1.64E+07    5.40E+04
6.90E+06    5.60E+04
3.18E+06    5.80E+04
1.58E+06    6.00E+04
8.35E+05    6.20E+04
4.64E+05    6.40E+04
2.69E+05    6.60E+04
1.62E+05    6.80E+04
1.01E+05    7.00E+04
6.47E+04    7.20E+04
4.25E+04    7.40E+04
2.86E+04    7.60E+04
1.96E+04    7.80E+04
1.37E+04    8.00E+04
9735.23     8.20E+04
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:
I'm adding data for two additional curves;

Curve at temperature 21C

```
3.98E+07    6.30E+04
1.58E+07    6.40E+04
4.03E+06    6.60E+04
1.47E+06    6.80E+04
6.57E+05    7.00E+04
3.37E+05    7.20E+04
1.91E+05    7.40E+04
1.16E+05    7.60E+04
7.49E+04    7.80E+04
5.04E+04    8.00E+04
3.52E+04    8.20E+04
2.53E+04    8.40E+04
1.87E+04    8.60E+04
1.41E+04    8.80E+04
1.08E+04    9.00E+04
8.47E+03    9.20E+04
```

Curve at temperature 537C

```
7.91E+06    3.80E+04
3.29E+06    4.00E+04
1.51E+06    4.20E+04
7.48E+05    4.40E+04
3.95E+05    4.60E+04
2.20E+05    4.80E+04
1.28E+05    5.00E+04
7.77E+04    5.20E+04
4.87E+04    5.40E+04
3.14E+04    5.60E+04
2.08E+04    5.80E+04
1.41E+04    6.00E+04
9.73E+03    6.20E+04
6.85E+03    6.40E+04
```

More info about the curves - These are alternating stress (y axis), number of cycles to failure (x axis) curves for a material at different temperatures.

Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like a job for a spreadsheet first and C++ second.

Comment: With 2 curves only, it is difficult to predict how a curve depends on the temperature. At least a 3rd curve would be useful for a first analysis

Comment: If you don't have more data, the best you can do is linear interpolation between the temperatures. But what are you going to do with the range where you have data for 420°C, but nut for 310°C? Or do the end points of the curves represent the same "state", except for temperature? How you interpolate also depends on what the curves represent.

Comment: @Damien, There's a strong possibility that there's 3 or more curves. I didn't add any more since I didn't want to complicate the question more.

Comment: @MOehm The curves are SN (y- stress/ x-number of cycles to failure) curves for a single material at different temperatures. Once it reaches a certain stress limit the 'state' continues for the x axis

Comment: Thanks. So neither of the x or y values are "input" values; they are both results from experiments, right? In that case I can't see a good way to interpolet. (But maybe someone else with better knowledge in the problem domain can.)

Comment: @Spektre I've added data for additional curves. "taking corresponding point from 4 neighboring curves and cubically interpolate" could you elaborate on this, an example/reference for cubic interpolation perhaps. Thanks.

Comment: @Spektre Thanks very much. Unfortunately I only have data for the above 4 curves. Ideally I should be able to interpolate with just 3 curves as well.

Comment: @Spektre It's 21C

Comment: let me recheck, I took them from 2 different applications, could be the issue

Comment: @Spektre I've fixed the data. There was a problem with 21C and 537C data

Comment: @Madz I moved my comments into answer and also added a simple C++ example you can use as a start point to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get simple example working. First of all your data must be ordered so the measurements must be sorted by temperature and each measurement must be ordered by `y` (stress). I used ascending order. First algorith:

1. **compute BBOX**

   simply compute min and max `x,y` coordinates of all measurements together. This will be used for conversion between logarithmic and linear scale and also for aligning.
2. **resample and align all measurements**

   so convert all of your measurements to form that it's samples are at the same `y` values (across all measurements). I used uniformly sampled `y` axis. So simply step is `(ymax-ymin)/(n-1)` where `n` is number of points of the resampled data. So all measurements will have the same size and all the `y` values will be the same across measurement on the same index. Missing `x` data will be filled with `0`.

   The resampling can be done in linear scale. I used [piecewise cubic interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22806242/2521214).
3. **create new measurement for new temperature**

   so simply create new measurement again containing `n`-points. The `y` value is the same as before (so just copy it from any of the aligned measurements) and then just take 1 point from each of the 4 measurements corresponding to the same point as we are processing and cubicaly interpolate its position. However **this must be done in logarithmic scale!**

   The valid range of temperature is between the 2nd and 3th measurement temperature.

Here preview using your data and 370 C:

[image: preview 370C]

And here C++/VCL example for this (just ignore the VCL stuff):

```cpp
//$$---- Form CPP ----
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <vcl.h>
#include <math.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#include "win_main.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
int xs,ys;              // screen resolution
Graphics::TBitmap *bmp; // back buffer bitmap for rendering
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// here starts the important stuff
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
float in[4][40]=        // input measureements format is: { temperature,x0,y0,x1,y1...,-1 }
    {{ 21.0,
    3.98E+07,6.30E+04,
    1.58E+07,6.40E+04,
    4.03E+06,6.60E+04,
    1.47E+06,6.80E+04,
    6.57E+05,7.00E+04,
    3.37E+05,7.20E+04,
    1.91E+05,7.40E+04,
    1.16E+05,7.60E+04,
    7.49E+04,7.80E+04,
    5.04E+04,8.00E+04,
    3.52E+04,8.20E+04,
    2.53E+04,8.40E+04,
    1.87E+04,8.60E+04,
    1.41E+04,8.80E+04,
    1.08E+04,9.00E+04,
    8.47E+03,9.20E+04,
    -1.0 },
    { 310.0,
    9.43E+06,6.00E+04,
    3.96E+06,6.20E+04,
    1.78E+06,6.40E+04,
    8.52E+05,6.60E+04,
    4.28E+05,6.80E+04,
    2.25E+05,7.00E+04,
    1.23E+05,7.20E+04,
    6.95E+04,7.40E+04,
    4.05E+04,7.60E+04,
    2.43E+04,7.80E+04,
    1.49E+04,8.00E+04,
    9.39E+03,8.20E+04,
    -1.0 },
    { 420.0,
    5.14E+08,4.80E+04,
    1.35E+08,5.00E+04,
    4.36E+07,5.20E+04,
    1.64E+07,5.40E+04,
    6.90E+06,5.60E+04,
    3.18E+06,5.80E+04,
    1.58E+06,6.00E+04,
    8.35E+05,6.20E+04,
    4.64E+05,6.40E+04,
    2.69E+05,6.60E+04,
    1.62E+05,6.80E+04,
    1.01E+05,7.00E+04,
    6.47E+04,7.20E+04,
    4.25E+04,7.40E+04,
    2.86E+04,7.60E+04,
    1.96E+04,7.80E+04,
    1.37E+04,8.00E+04,
    9735.23 ,8.20E+04,
    -1.0 },
    { 537.0,
    7.91E+06,3.80E+04,
    3.29E+06,4.00E+04,
    1.51E+06,4.20E+04,
    7.48E+05,4.40E+04,
    3.95E+05,4.60E+04,
    2.20E+05,4.80E+04,
    1.28E+05,5.00E+04,
    7.77E+04,5.20E+04,
    4.87E+04,5.40E+04,
    3.14E+04,5.60E+04,
    2.08E+04,5.80E+04,
    1.41E+04,6.00E+04,
    9.73E+03,6.20E+04,
    6.85E+03,6.40E+04,
    -1.0 }};             
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// temp and output data
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
const n=40;                         // points to resmaple curves with
float dat[4][2+n+n];                // resampled input curves
float out[2+n+n];                   // interpolated curve
float xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax;          // BBOX
void resample(float *out,float *in,float y0,float y1)   // resample and align y to range and n points and store it to out
    {
    float t,d1,d2,a0,a1,a2,a3,x,y,x0,x1,x2,x3;
    int i,ii,i0,i1,i2,i3,nn;
    // scan how many points in[] has
    for (nn=0,i=1;in[i]>=0.0;i+=2) nn++;
    // resample input curves to n points
    out[0]=in[0];           // copy T
    out[n+n+1]=-1;          // end of data
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
        // y uniformly distributed and aligned in the dat array
        y=y0+((y1-y0)*float(i)/float(n-1));
        ii=1+i +i ;
        // check if range present
        if ((y<in[1+1])||(y>in[1+nn-1+nn-1+1]))
            {
            out[ii+0]=0.0;
            out[ii+1]=y;
            continue;
            }
        // find i1 so in[i1] <= y < in[i1+1]
        // linear search, can be replaced with binary search
        for (i1=0;i1<nn;i1++) if (in[1+i1+i1+1]>=y) break;
        if (in[1+i1+i1+1]>y) i1--;
        // neigboring indexes
        i0=i1-1; if (i0<  0) i0=   0;
        i2=i1+1; if (i2>=nn) i2=nn-1;
        i3=i1+2; if (i3>=nn) i3=nn-1;
        // convert to array index
        i0=1+i0+i0;
        i1=1+i1+i1;
        i2=1+i2+i2;
        i3=1+i3+i3;
        // parameter is based on y value
        d1=y-in[i1+1];
        d2=in[i2+1]-in[i1+1];
        if (fabs(d2)>1e-6) t=d1/d2; else t=0.0;
        // points to interpolate
        x0=in[i0];
        x1=in[i1];
        x2=in[i2];
        x3=in[i3];
        // cubic interpoaltion of x
        d1=0.5*(x2-x0);
        d2=0.5*(x3-x1);
        a0=x1;
        a1=d1;
        a2=(3.0*(x2-x1))-(2.0*d1)-d2;
        a3=d1+d2+(2.0*(-x2+x1));
        x=a0+(a1*t)+(a2*t*t)+(a3*t*t*t);
        if (x<0.0) x=0.0;   // just to be sure data is not messed up
        // copy point
        out[ii+0]=x;
        out[ii+1]=y;
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void interpolate(float *out,float T) // interpolate out[] as n point curve from dat[4][] matching temperature T
    {                                // dat[][] must be ordered ascending by T,x,y
    int i,ii;                        // valid T range is <dat[1][0],dat[2][0]>
    float t,d1,d2,a0,a1,a2,a3,x,x0,x1,x2,x3,t0,t1,t2,t3;
    out[0]=T;               // copy T
    out[n+n+1]=-1;          // end of data
    // parameter from T
    t=(T-dat[1][0])/(dat[2][0]-dat[1][0]);
    t0=dat[0][0];
    t1=dat[1][0];
    t2=dat[2][0];
    t3=dat[3][0];
    // cubic interpolation between curves
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
        // points to interpolate
        ii=1+i+i;
        x0=dat[0][ii];
        x1=dat[1][ii];
        x2=dat[2][ii];
        x3=dat[3][ii];
        // logarithm scale
        (x0>=xmin)?x0=log(x0/xmin)/log(xmax/xmin):x0=0.0;
        (x1>=xmin)?x1=log(x1/xmin)/log(xmax/xmin):x1=0.0;
        (x2>=xmin)?x2=log(x2/xmin)/log(xmax/xmin):x2=0.0;
        (x3>=xmin)?x3=log(x3/xmin)/log(xmax/xmin):x3=0.0;
        out[ii+1]=dat[0][ii+1]; // copy y
        // too much missing data
        if ((x1<=0.0)||(x2<=0.0)){ out[ii+0]=0; continue; }
        // mirror missing data
        if (x0<=0.0) x0=x1-((x2-x1)*(t1-t0)/(t2-t1));
        if (x3<=0.0) x3=x2+((x2-x1)*(t3-t2)/(t2-t1));
        // interpolate x
        d1=0.5*(x2-x0);
        d2=0.5*(x3-x1);
        a0=x1;
        a1=d1;
        a2=(3.0*(x2-x1))-(2.0*d1)-d2;
        a3=d1+d2+(2.0*(-x2+x1));
        x=a0+(a1*t)+(a2*t*t)+(a3*t*t*t);
        if (x<0.0) x=0.0;   // just to be sure data is not messed up
        else x=exp(x*log(xmax/xmin))*xmin; // back to linear scale
        out[ii+0]=x;
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void minmax(float *dat,bool _reset) // compute BBOX of the curves
    {
    int i;
    float x,y;
    for (i=1;dat[i]>=0.0;)
        {
        x=dat[i]; i++;
        y=dat[i]; i++;
        if (x<=0.0) continue;
        if (_reset){ xmin=xmax=x; ymin=ymax=y; _reset=false; }
        if (xmin>x) xmin=x;
        if (xmax<x) xmax=x;
        if (ymin>y) ymin=y;
        if (ymax<y) ymax=y;
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void toscr(float &x,float &y)   // convert x,y from plot data to screen coordinates (just for rendering)
    {
    float x0,dx,y1,dy;
    // range <0,1>
//  x=(x-xmin)/(xmax-xmin);                         // linear
//  y=(y-ymin)/(ymax-ymin);                         // linear
    (x>=xmin)?x=log(x/xmin)/log(xmax/xmin):x=0.0;   // logarithmic
    (y>=ymin)?y=log(y/ymin)/log(ymax/ymin):y=0.0;   // logarithmic
    // view
    x0=0.1*xs; dx=0.8*xs;
    y1=0.9*ys; dy=0.8*ys;
    // [pixels]
    x=x0+x*dx;
    y=y1-y*dy;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void plot(float *dat,TColor col)// renders measurement data (just for rendering)
    {
    int i,e;
    float x,y,r=2;
    // curve
    bmp->Canvas->Pen->Color=col;
    bmp->Canvas->Font->Color=col;
    for (e=1,i=1;dat[i]>=0.0;)
        {
        x=dat[i]; i++;
        y=dat[i]; i++;
        if (x<=0.0) continue;
        toscr(x,y);
        if (e)
            {
            bmp->Canvas->TextOutA(x,y,AnsiString().sprintf("%.0f C",dat[0]));
            bmp->Canvas->MoveTo(x,y);
            e=0;
            }
        else bmp->Canvas->LineTo(x,y);
        }
    // points
    for (i=1;dat[i]>=0.0;)
        {
        x=dat[i]; i++;
        y=dat[i]; i++;
        if (x<=0.0) continue;
        toscr(x,y);
        bmp->Canvas->Ellipse(x-r,y-r,x+r,y+r);
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void draw() // just render of my App
    {
    bmp->Canvas->Brush->Color=clWhite;
    bmp->Canvas->FillRect(TRect(0,0,xs,ys));

    plot(dat[0],clRed);
    plot(dat[1],clGreen);
    plot(dat[2],clBlue);
    plot(dat[3],clBlack);

    plot(out,clMaroon);

    Form1->Canvas->Draw(0,0,bmp);
//  bmp->SaveToFile("out.bmp");
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner):TForm(Owner) // init of my app
    {
    // init backbuffer
    bmp=new Graphics::TBitmap;
    bmp->HandleType=bmDIB;
    bmp->PixelFormat=pf32bit;
    // here prepare data (important)
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<4;i++) minmax(in[i],i==0);
    for (i=0;i<4;i++) resample(dat[i],in[i],ymin,ymax);
    // here create new data for T=370[C]
    interpolate(out,370.0);
    // and also include it to the BBOX for rendering
    minmax(out,false);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormDestroy(TObject *Sender) // not important just destructor of my App
    {
    delete bmp;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormResize(TObject *Sender) // not important just resize event
    {
    xs=ClientWidth;
    ys=ClientHeight;
    bmp->Width=xs;
    bmp->Height=ys;
    draw();
    }
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormPaint(TObject *Sender) // not important just repaint event
    {
    draw();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

See function `TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)` on how to use this.

However physical validity is questionable You should test if this kind of interpolation leads to valid data by having 5 measurements. Use 4 to interpolate the 5th and check if they overlap If not then this might need additional tweaking like increasing the interpolation polynomial degree, or use log scale also for resampling etc ...

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer, I'll try this out and let you know.

Comment: @Madz ok... btw what material is this? as you got `x=5.14E+08` cycles on one measurement which is odd I always taught that `10^7` cycles is the top limit and anything that survive that is immune to stress of the same or lower force (`y`) no matter how many cycles ... unless some additional stress force is added

Comment: It's alloy steel, I can't vouch for the validity of the data though.

Comment: @Madz I was just curious ... its not my field of engineering I am more IT+EE+research

Comment: @Madz btw IIRC the stuff can be also computed unless my memory play tricks on me there should be some formula to obtain `x` from `y` if you know the shape/dimensions of material and its mechanical constants. But it was ages ago when I was in school so I might remember wrongly.... however I do not think it was temp related (as the constants change with temp it might be just hidden in those)

Comment: I don't have that data with me unfortunately, but I'll look into it. Thanks.

Comment: @Madz Also I am not sure about this but my guts are telling me you should be aware of [Curie temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curie_temperature) its possible the mechanical stress properties change there (but that is just my guess) so if the case you should not use measurements below and above it together as the input for interpolation. Iron has `770` however alloys can be anything around so `537C` might be a problem